# Subspace given a algebraic condition for the vectors in it

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need to verify if the set:

$$U = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3|x^2+y+z = 0\}$$

is a subspace or not.

However, I don't know how to deal with these algebraic equations that the vectors must satisfy. For example., I know that the $0$ vector is in $U$, but:

$$u\in U\implies u = \{(x_1,y_1,z_1)\in\mathbb R^3|x_1^2 + y_1 + z_1 = 0\}$$
$$v\in U\implies v = \{(x_2,y_2,z_2)\in\mathbb R^3|x_2^2 + y_2 + z_2 = 0\}$$

$$u+v = (x_1+y_1, y_1 + y_2, z_1 + z_2)$$ and I need to verify if in $u+v$, the rule

$$(x_1+x_2)^2 + y_1+y_2 + z_1 + z_2 = 0$$

How to verify this is true/ If not, how to prove this relation isn't true, without using a counterxample?

Comment: Why you do not want a counterexample?

Comment: The most compelling way to show a relation is false is by using a counterexample.

Comment: @Pgatti I know how to find a counterexample but suppose the condition was so hard that I couldn't find a counterexample easely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, writing $u = \{(x_1, y_1, z_1) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x_1^2 + y_1 + z_1\}$ is wrong. The right hand side of the equality is a set, namely $U$, while the left hand side is a vector in $U$. What you want to write is $u = (x_1, y_1, z_1)$ where $x_1^2 + y_1 + z_1 = 0$; this ensures $u \in U$.

Suppose then that $u = (x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $v = (x_2, y_2, z_2)$ with $x_1^2 + y_1 + z_1 = 0$ and $x_2^2 + y_2 + z_2 = 0$. Is $u + v \in U$? We just need to check whether the algebraic condition that determines $U$ is satisfied by the components of $u + v = (x_1 + x_2, y_1 + y_2, z_1 + z_2)$. To that end, we have

\begin{align*}
(x_1 + x_2)^2 + (y_1 + y_2) + (z_1 + z_2) &= x_1^2 + 2x_1x_2 + x_2 + y_1 + y_2 + z_1 + z_2\\
&= (x_1^2 + y_1 + z_1) + (x_2^2 + y_2 + z_2) + 2x_1x_2\\
&= 0 + 0 + 2x_1x_2\\
&= 2x_1x_2.
\end{align*}

In general, $2x_1x_2 \neq 0$, so the components of $u+v$ do not satisfy the equation which determines $U$ and therefore $u + v \notin U$.

Note, the above calculation shows us how to construct counterexamples to the claim $u, v \in U \Longrightarrow u + v \in U$. Namely, if $u$ and $v$ are chosen such that $x_1 \neq 0$ and $x_2 \neq 0$, then $2x_1x_2 \neq 0$ so $u + v \notin U$.

Answer (score 1):

$(x_1+x_2)^2+y_1+y_2+z_1+z_2=x_1^2+x_2^2+2x_1x_2+y_1+z_1+y_2+z_2=(x_1^2+y_1+z_1)+(x_2^2+y_2+z_2)+2x_1x_2$

Now we have an extra term $2x_1x_2$ which will vanish only if $x_1=0 $ or $x_2=0$.So  that is why it will not be subspace